# How reliable is to check error code 200 to detect an authorization error?

Tags: facebook, authorization, facebook-fql

I am trying to identify when an action without authorization has been made.
Is it 100% returning error code 200  in those situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to post an action without sufficient permission, you'll get HTTP status code 403 and content like "'{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}'"